# How to deal with a negative pole (unstable) in the pre-filter of a control system?

Tags: filters, filter-design, transfer-function, analog, control-systems

So while answering how to design a PI controller for a first order time delayed system   [(Question Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25635/design-of-a-pi-controller) )

Here is the closed loop equation to a control system:

$$
G_C(s) = \frac{\frac{K}{T}(1-sT)(s)} { s^3 + (\frac{1}{T} + a - KK_p)s^2 + (\frac{a}{T} + \frac{KK_P}{T} +K_I)s+\frac{KK_I}{T}} 
$$

**Question:** How do you deal with normalizing the numerator in your closed loop transfer function when the filter is unstable? (Pole on RH of plane)

Typically you introduce a filter before your controller that does:

$$ \frac{1} {\frac{K}{T} (1-sT)(s)} $$

to normalize the numerator

But the filter itself is unstable because of the term:

$$ \frac{1}{(1-sT)}$$ is unstable for a step response which would create an issue realizing the system at all.

One way I've thought about dealing with this is multiplying it by its complex conjugate 
$$
\frac{(1+sT)} {(1+sT)}$$

but im not really sure about the merits of it.

Comment: Good question. Controls have never been my strong suit, but are you sure that you would want to add a filter to the loop with that response? Since it's a closed-loop system, adding a filter $F(s)$ to the feedback arm doesn't just multiply the closed-loop transfer function by $F(s)$. Also, I'm not sure what multiplication by the complex conjugate would do; the pole is still there in the right-half plane.

Comment: the complex conjugate is a time delay.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. $\frac{1+sT}{1+sT} = 1$, not a time delay. And if you introduce that filter inside the feedback loop, it doesn't just multiply the closed-loop transfer function (because of the feedback). If you were trying just to cancel the zero, you would want it outside of the loop. As you noted, however, such a filter would be unstable. It's possible that this is just par for the course with PI control; excessive delay in the loop causes instability due to the integrator. Note that if the delay is small in the original system, $e^{-sT} \approx 1$, and could be neglected.

Comment: @JasonR I was thinking about reformulating the equation by using the complex conjugate to write a more suitable circuit.

Comment: Why do you want to normalise the numerator?

Comment: normalizing the numerator makes analysis of the equation (and subsequent tuning) much easier.  Basically you'd look at the denominator to determine the transfer function characteristics (damping coefficient, rise time etc)

Answer (score 1):

In general, in order to stabilise a system, however complex, if you have the transfer function $G(s)$, you introduce a feedback loop with a new function $F(s)$.

Write the closed loop transfer function for the new system with the added $F(s)$, and then find $F(s)$ in order for the new system to be stable. This is like the first exercise in any control book in order to offer an example of stabilising a system via negative Feedback.

Check the book from Ogata on control engineering for reference.